# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn значение выбранного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Имеется DataGrid в котором присутствует колонка DataGridComboBoxColumn, значения для данного поля заполняются поиском при вводе некоторых символов, проблема в том что после выбора элемента в ComboBox и переключении фокуса на другую ячейку не видно выбранного элемента. В какую сторону копать, подскажите?:

```
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="300"
                                    Header="Полное наименование"
                                    IsReadOnly="False"
                                    SelectedValuePath="Key">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ProductModelCombo.ListProductCombo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ComboTextProduct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding SelectedComboProduct, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBoxBase.TextChanged">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsDropDownOpen">
                                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True" />
                                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=ProductModelObject.Quantity}"
                                Header="Кол-во"
                                IsReadOnly="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=ProductModelObject.ProductSale.RetailPrice}"
                                Header="Розничная цена"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=ProductModelObject.ProductSale.Barcode}"
                                Header="Штрих-код"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

`ProductModelCombo.ListProductCombo` - имеет тип `Dictionary<int, string>`

Comment: SelectedComboProduct работает? никто его не трет? null не засовывает?

Comment: SelectedComboProduct работает, с ним всё в порядке.все данные подтягиваются и отображаются, а вот именно с колонкой combobox проблема. Можно конечно заменить на datagridtemplatecolumn и вставить туда комбо, но хотелось бы по эстетичнее сделать

Comment: datagridtemplatecolumn по моему и есть более эстетичный вариант :). Возможно дело в <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>. Т.е. Только в режиме Edit, судя по названию. Оттого и когда идет переключение в ShowStyle или как то так, слетает и биндинг, задаваемый стилем.

Comment: DataGridComboBoxColumn.DefaultElementStyle добавить нужно. С соответствующим binding-ом.

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Судя по логике вы правы. Чуть позже попробую реализовать

Comment: Всё получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @Arheus будет отлично, если вы напишите ответ, а не просто комментарий ;)